# Merge csv in another folder location

Tags: csv, batch-file, merge, copy

I'm trying to merge csv files into one text file using a batch file.

My batch file is located in `C:\Users\aallen` and the CSV files are located in  `C:\Users\aallen\Test`

The batch file will only work when its located in the same location as the csv.

I have tried the following commands with no joy:

1) `cd "C:\Users\aallen\Test" copy *csv test.csv`
2) `copy "C:\Users\aallen\Test" *csv test.csv`

What I'm I missing?

Comment: `copy "C:\Users\aallen\Test\*.csv" test.csv`

Comment: Thanks Stephan..  If I want the merge file in another location what command would I need

Comment: `copy "C:\Users\aallen\Test\*.csv" "d:\new location\test.csv"`

Comment: Currently the headers are duplicated within the merged file. What command would only give me the headers once at the top?

Answer (score 1):

Collecting the information from Question and Comments, you want to combine several CSV files into one, but only keep the headerline once.

`more +1` is able to show a file, skipping first lines (see `more /?`), but `more +1 *.csv` does only skip the first line of the first file and keeps it at all other files (just the opposite of what you need). So you have to process one file after the other with a `for` loop and check for first file yourself (can be done with a flag-variable (`flag` here). Redirect the whole loop to your resultfile.

```
@echo off
set "first=yes"
(for %%a in ("C:\Users\aallen\Test\*.csv") do (
  if defined first (
    type "%%a"
    set "first="
  ) else (
    more +1 "%%a"
  )
))>"d:\new location\test.csv"
```

Note: `more` at command line prints just one screen and then pauses until you press a key. But when you use it in a batchfile, it doesn't (well, to be honest, it does, but after ~65000 lines. I hope, your files are shorter)